# When do we have to use an analog oscilloscope?

Tags: analog, adc, oscilloscope

Are there any testing/measurement processes in electric and electronic engineering that can be done **only with an  analog oscilloscope**?

In digital scopes there is a short delay to process the signal (analog to digital conversion) then display it on the LCD, so maybe some very fast pulses could be missed due to dead time.

While the analog scope displays the signal instantly.

Comment: I can't imagine anything where that delay would be significant.

Comment: Any delay in processing a signal to display it on a screen is probably much less than the delay of someone looking at the screen and thinking about what it means.

Comment: OK. Any other advantage for analog scope in compare to digital one? I have seen some graphic adapter that displaying some image on the scope display (XY Mode), they can't be used with digital scopes, does that means there are weakness in digital scope ?

Comment: why can't it be used with a digital scope? There are lots of digital scopes with xy mode.

Comment: I know. But the graphic image on the DSO are not clear, while on the AO display very clear. (I'm taking about graphic adapters that showing some image on the scope display).

Comment: You don't say **how** the image isn't clear.  I've certanly seen graphics on analog scopes that leverage the fact that fast-moving traces are dimmer than slower ones, in lieu of a z-channel.  Are your DSO images cluttered with unnecessary lines connecting the bits?

Comment: Fancy visual effects in XY mode look nicer on analog scopes. For example old vector arcade games.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm not agree with your first comment, the point here is not the human eyes time response, but the dead time that happens in the processing delay in DSO can missing some fast pulses in the input signal, so not appears on the display.

Comment: @M.A.K I think you misunderstand how the scope handles processing delay. It sounds like you think the scope takes a sample, processes it while ignoring everything in between, and then takes another sample. If the scope can't process a continuous stream of data as fast as it comes in, then to prevent an infinitely increasing backlog of sample data, it samples and stores data for one or multiple trigger intervals and then ignores subsequent trigger intervals while it processes the data and displays it on the screen (at least, I am fairly certain this is how scopes handle things).

Comment: So it would not actually miss a fast pulse within its bandwidth and sampling rate that was occurring regularly enough to fall into its trigger intervals where it was sampling. What it would miss are spurious fast pulses that somehow *only* occur during these processing intervals where the scope is busy processing, not sampling, and ignoring triggers. I'm not sure how such a signal could exist unless it was specifically engineered to not be observable on that particular model of digital scope.

Answer (score 13):

Modern digital oscilloscopes can process 10's of thousands of waveform updates a second. The dead time is a very small proportion of the time and for triggered operation does not interfere with the ability of the scope to capture signals at all. A digital scope has the ability to capture for long periods before the arrival of the trigger - analog scopes are limited to the length of the delay line; only a few nanoseconds.

The sampling of the signal can introduce aliasing artifacts that can be difficult to interpret but again modern scopes do well at minimize the effect of those as well.

The main reason I've turned to an analogue scope is when I'm analyzing low level analogue circuitry where the noise level of the scope can be important; often the front-end noise of a digital scope is worse than analogue ones. Also when viewing a signal with a significant level of noise the inherent averaging that occurs with the phosphor of a conventional scope can be easier to interpret than with a digital scope.

But digital scopes are getting better and I haven't had to use an analogue scope for many years. The averaging capabilities have improved to give a more similar response to analogue scopes and with the signal processing capabilities (such as scan averaging, colored probability displays etc) now exceed those of conventional scopes.

Although I have many scopes I have collected over the years I'm sorry to say that traditional ones have had their day and are now relegated to being conversation pieces.

Comment: I think you mean *waveform* updates, not screen updates. Multiple waveforms are drawn per screen refresh.

Comment: While they don't update the screen 10000 times per second, they can offer wave-update rates that high, essentially showing that much traces per second.

Comment: I am pretty sure scopes on periodic sampling skip periods waveforms too to compensate for processing time unless they can process and display data faster than it is coming in otherwise an infinitely increasingly amount of data backlog would accumulate. DAQs don't skip since they must record all data but also have much slower sampling rates.

Comment: I was 'gifted' a Rigol DS1054Z for a while, and was disappointed. It was harder to operate than my analog scope and didn't capture the nuances of waveforms. Aliasing and noise were annoying and reduced confidence. No doubt it would be a great scope for digital work, but for analog I prefer my old scope. I sent the Rigol back even though I could have kept it (at no cost) if I wanted.

Comment: @Hearth - true that is a better way to say it.

Comment: One of my favorite analog 'scopes was the Tek 2467B BrightEye.  For those not familiar, this was standard analog 'scope but with an image intensifier fitted to the display.  This allowed to you to see fleeting and low rate events, such as an occasional glitch on a clock.

Comment: @SteveSh - I've never used a 2476. I like my 2445. I also have a 2465 and a dozen other lesser scopes) but I normally use a TDS3014

Answer (score 4):

You can get by without an analog scope if you understand the issues with a sampling system. Plus, you may be looking at signals that are well suited for a DSO and won't miss what an analog scope has to offer. While I mostly use a DSO these days since I'm looking at low repetition rate pulse waveforms, utilize the math functions, and capture waveforms for post processing analysis. I still turn to my 465 or 475 scopes for certain tasks.

When looking at noise in analog circuits:

- I use an analog scope since the noise floor is much better than a
  DSO and am not fighting quantization issues with small signals. Many DSOs digitally amplify the most sensitive vertical setting which creates an ugly waveform.
- You can visually pick out the characteristics of the noise on an
  analog scope. This is helpful in identifying sources of interference buried in noise. Digital scopes I've used (USD 1000 to 25000 price range) don't do well in this respect.
- The old Tekronix scopes have magical triggering that the new fangled
  digital scopes don't come close to. This is important when looking at interference with a regular pattern.
- A quick glance at a noise waveform will give me the approximate rms voltage of Gaussian noise on an analog scope (\$ Vrms \approx Vpp/6 \$). Digital scopes don't mimic the persistence of P31 phospher well enough to make this sort of judgment, or more likely, I'm not used to using a digital scope for this sort of eyeball measurement since the intensity adjustment mucks with the virtual persistence.

I'll sometimes back up the digital scope reading with my analog scope to make sure aliasing isn't an issue. Been burned by aliasing and anti-aliasing (low-pass) filters issues too many times.

Unwanted oscillations in circuitry can be missed by digital scopes if the sweep rate (sample rate) isn't fast enough. If you make the sweep rate fast enough, then you can't see low-freq issues. Overshoot will be missed or misleading by digital scopes if the sweep rate isn't fast enough. This is less of an issue if you use an expensive DSO.

Analog scopes have a superior front panel layout and interface. No bloody menus! When examining unknown circuits or bringing up new projects, being able to make scope adjustments quickly saves time & frustration.

If I need to make a quick measurement, I'll turn to an analog scope since I don't need to wait for the operating system to boot and the self test.

The dead time in digital scopes is too long compared to analog scopes. True, this has gotten better over the past couple decades, but DSO's still are lacking which makes looking at noise problematic for me.

On the bright side, DSOs are a source of entertainment when watching engineers fresh out of college fighting with DSOs since they don't understand the issues one can have with a sampling system.

Still use the Tek 7000 mainframe with the TDR plugins. The 25ps rise time allows me to see small scale impedance bumps in interconnects.

Answer (score 2):

Once had a 12-bit signal-acquisition system (4 channels of InfraRed images) where all 4 of the ADCs lost the 5 LSBs below about 3/8 scale. Those bits, instead of being wonderfully clean in the transitions (about 90 microvolt wide transitions from one code to another ), seemed to be just random.

Nothing seemed to change the behavior.

Took the Tek 900MHz 3pF active probe (X1, type P6201) into 7A26 500MHz vertical with 7B92 sweep (500pS fastest time/div) in the non-storage Tek 7904.

And yes, out at 900 MHz (no aliasing in the system), well-stabilized by the sweep trigger, was about 10 milliVolts of oscillation, showing up on -5 volt rail, across SMT bypass capacitors and the GND plane.

Cure was to place at least 22 ohms in series with the Analog Vin to the ADC. Something about THAT PCB, THAT LAYOUT, and that I had FOUR ADCs running synchronously.

We shipped a bunch of these cameras, with 33 ohms installed.

In later years I've wondered how I could have diagnosed that otherwise.

Today, my favorite plugin on the Tek7904 is the 7A22, down to 10 uV/division, to measure magnetic coupling thru sheets of metal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on some Amateur Radio equipment, and neither 100 MHz digital scope can capture an amplitude modulated HF signal. Even my old 20 MHz Leader beats a 100 MHz digital scope.

Comment: What scopes are these that you're using? What frequency is the signal? I find it hard to believe that a *good* 100 MHz digital scope would fail to capture an AM signal at probably a handful of MHz.

Comment: The signal is 28 Mhz. The 20 Mhz scope is a Leader 1021. The 100 Mhz scopes are a Rigol (not sure what model; had to givebut back). The other is a FNIRISI 5012H handheld 100Mhz scope. My better scope is under repair Tek 465.